# Why are all of the classes in Rakudo's src/core/Int.pm declared with my?

Tags: raku, lexical-scope

Looking at the [source for Int](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/nom/src/core/Int.pm), I see that all of the classes are declared with `my`, which I would have thought would make them private and not available outside that file. But, they obviously are. Why do they need to be declared that way?

```
my class Rat { ... }
my class X::Numeric::DivideByZero { ... }
my class X::NYI::BigInt { ... }

my class Int { ... }
my subset UInt of Int where {not .defined or $_ >= 0};

my class Int does Real { # declared in BOOTSTRAP
```

I figure that BOOTSTRAP comment has something to do with it. In the [Perl6/Metamodel/BOOTSTRAP.nqp](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/nom/src/Perl6/Metamodel/BOOTSTRAP.nqp) there are lines like:

```
my stub Int metaclass Perl6::Metamodel::ClassHOW { ... };
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The files in Rakudo's `src/core/` directory are not compiled as separate modules with their own private file-level scope, but concatenated into a single file such as `gen/moar/CORE.setting` during the build proceess.

Sematically, this 'setting' (known as 'prelude' in other languges) forms an outer lexical scope implicitly surrounding your program.

The design is described in [S02: Pseudo-packages](http://design.perl6.org/S02.html#Pseudo-packages), and parts of that section have made it into the [official documentation](https://docs.perl6.org/language/packages#Pseudo-packages).

Comment: Well, the design might be described in those docs, but I wouldn't have thought that it was connected to what was going on in Int.pm. Thanks,